# List Validation settings Error in Formula

Tags: validation-list-items, formula

I am trying make the Billing Status field required only when the A La Carte field is checked (true) or not blank (otherwise it is not required). I don't know whether to set this up in infopath or on the Sharepoint list or if it is possible?

How do I get this formula to work in List Validation settings?

```
IF([A La Carte]"Yes",(AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Billing Status])),TRUE)
```

Comment: What all are your conditions?

Comment: Also there is syntax error in your formula: `[A La Carte]="Yes"`

Comment: I'm trying make the Billing Status field required only when the A La Carte field is checked (true) or not blank (otherwise it is not required). I don't know whether to set this up in infopath or on the Sharepoint list or if it is possible?

Comment: When I put this in the List Validation settings nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all your requirements. But I guess you want "Billing Status" field to be mandatory if "A La Carte" is equal to "Yes"(Correct me if I am wrong).

In this case you need to use below formula:

```
IF([A La Carte]="Yes",NOT(ISBLANK([Billing Status])),TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you tried this yet? Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I'm trying make the Billing Status field required only when the A La Carte field is checked (true) or not blank (otherwise it is not required). I don't know whether to set this up in infopath or on the Sharepoint list or if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably need a better description of your requirements. But here's a guess:

```
=AND( [A La Carte] = "Yes", NOT( ISBLANK( [BillingStatus] ) ) )
```

If "A La Carte" is a Yes/No column then use this:

```
=AND( [A La Carte], NOT( ISBLANK( [BillingStatus] ) ) )
```

This indicates:

```
A La Carte = Yes    BillingStatus has any value     item is valid
A La Carte = No     BillingStatus has any value     item is NOT valid
A La Carte = Yes    BillingStatus is blank          item is NOT valid
A La Carte = No     BillingStatus is blank          item is NOT valid
```

Note that an IF statement is not needed as validation formulas only need to return True or False, and AND does that.