# List Validation settings (Required Fields)

Tags: validation, infopath-rules

I am trying make the Billing Status (Dropdown) field required only when the A La Carte (Yes/No) field is checked (true) or not blank (otherwise it is not required).

Bascially, I only want to have certain fields to become required if the A La Carte (Field) is checked. I don't know whether to set this up in infopath or on the Sharepoint list or if it is possible?

I tried putting:

```
IF([A La Carte]="Yes",NOT(ISBLANK([Billing Status])),TRUE)
```

in the validation settings but I was still able to save the form without being prevented by the required fields.

Comment: Did you try the second answer in your original question? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259517/list-validation-settings-error-in-formula

Comment: I still cant get it to work using List Validation settings do I use Infopath instead?

Comment: You should not need InfoPath. You have added more info above... the A La Carte column is a Yes/No. That was not in the original question. I have updated the answer in the original question for a Yes/No column. (=AND( [A La Carte], NOT( ISBLANK( [BillingStatus] ) ) ))